# cmake4eclipse - why are the CMAKE providers deprecated

Tags: eclipse, cmake

I am trying to index large CMake projects which depend on one another and the only documentation I found on how to do that, is [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1094239/) from 2018.

The last post there says to enable inside `C/C++ General > Preprocesor include paths` the 2 providers "CMAKE_COMPILE_COMMANDS_JSON Parser" and "CMAKE_COMPILE_COMMANDS_JSON Compiler Built-Ins", however in recent versions of cmake4eclipse these are deprecated. I could not find a changelog explaining why or the workarounds.

How to solve the problem of missing includes?

**Edit**: I would also like to know - is it possible to resolve the includes without building from Eclipse (but merely by running the configure step perhaps). It's less useful to build from Eclipse but the Indexer functionality critically depends on having the correct includes.

Answer (score 2):

Because of lack of manpower/community contributors to maintain these.

Use CMake Compilation DB instead, it is the default for newly created projects.

You could have foung the answer by yourself at https://github.com/15knots/cmake4eclipse/issues/157 .

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I did look for the reason of deprecation but that page didn't show up.

The issue refers to  a _"compilation database parser coming with next CDT release"_, *which version does that refer to*?. I'm using CDT 10.5 with which I get "parsing error" from the database parser but the 2 deprecated parsers seem to make the indexer work well.

Comment: @haelix CDT 10.5 is OK.

Comment: @haelix The refernced compilation database parser is named 'CMake Compilation DB' (sorry, I do not know how to attach a screenshot here). Also see: Cmake4eclipse User Guide > Tasks > Configuring an Eclipse C-project or C++-project in the online help.